# What are good books on economic world history?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, reference-request, history, economic-history

I am trying to find a book that covers human history with a special focus on economics. It should answer questions like:

- What economic systems prevailed during which eras?
- How did these systems work in detail?
- How did economic organization evolve (Not just since the industrial revolution)?
- Were there civilizations which particularily focused on economic development?

It should NOT be a history of economic thought, like e.g. Niall Kishtainy's "A little history of economics".

Answer (score 1):

Rondo Cameron's [A Concise Economic History of the World](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Concise-Economic-History-World-Paleolithic/dp/0195127056) may be helpful. I read an early edition many years ago and it certainly is primarily economic history rather than history of economic thought. One limitation however, identified in [this review](https://academic.oup.com/ahr/article-abstract/95/5/1496/70168?redirectedFrom=fulltext), is that despite its title it focuses mainly on Europe.

Answer (score 0):

Only book I can think of is [The Economics Book Big Ideas simply explained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756698278).
But as the tittle says it is about Ideas and not the economic system of different civilizations. And everything is explained "SIMPLY".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also "Why nations fail" from Daron Acemoglu!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Felipe Fernandez-Armesto and The World: a History

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/013113499X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013113499X)

It is an easy read and is rather less eurocentric. Starts from the close ancestors of humankind, has a good emphasis on early societies and definitely brilliant reading list at the end of every chapter.

Also, in addition to Acemoğlu, Jared Diamond and Gregory Clark would be a good start. The books are called "guns, germs and steel" and "a farewell to alms" respectively.

Comment: FYI, if you look at the url shared, everything after "ref" can be removed, as a matter of habit, to prevent sharing unnecessary information (more relevant for some cases than others). For example, https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/013113499X is a complete link, and so is https://www.amazon.com/World-History-Combined-Felipe-Fernandez-Armesto/dp/013113499X.

Answer (score 0):

https://mobile.audible.com/pd/History/An-Economic-History-of-the-World-since-1400-Audiobook/B01K4ZNTFS?ref=msw_search_c1_0_1_AN

I recommend this — there isn’t a written format. You can choose Amazon Video, Audible Audiobook, or DVD.

Highly recommended, however.